# how to use shell-exec in php to generate server keys for VPN?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I want to make aphp web bage that will generate the server keys and client keys

for openVPN .
i generate one batch file that have init-config.bat and clean-all.bat ..and ects (all batch files) neccessary to generate the server keys and it work

now i wont to make aphp web bage that will generate the server keys and client keys 
 using shell-exec ,please help me.

best regards

Comment: And what is your question exactly? Could you show the code you have come up with?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the function `exec()`

Like:

```
$command = exec("C:\init-config.bat <param1> <param2> <...>");
echo $command; // debug purpose
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php